# How to show arrows using input type="number" in Vue 3?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

When I try to add input type="number" in my Vue 3 project, arrows doesn't show up like this:

[image]

Does anyone ever had this problem?

I tried to replicate what I'm doing on CodeSandbox in order to show here because I thought I was missing something in my code, but on CodeSandbox it works just normally. This happens in all my Vue projects.

I can solve this by making my own arrows, but I was just wondering why this is not working.

**Edit**

I'm also not able to edit the arrows. I was trying to maybe force them to appear but I couldn't do it

[image]

But maybe that's a hint, idk

Comment: Got a CSS UI framework maybe? Compare the DOM in both cases (your project vs vanilla ones).

Comment: I didn't add a CSS framework yet, I just added some basic styles at <style scoped>

Comment: I added Tailwind now but it's still not showing up. For some reason the arrows are hidden :(

Comment: Check your devtools to inspect the DOM and spot a difference then.